# Exporting my Blender models texture to unity

Tags: modeling, unity

I am able to export my model but my texture doesn't export with it, I've tried to export my texture separately and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but I found a video that tells me so when I export it separately it gives me a file. The file only gives my model the same texture it had when i exported it to unity (Grey). I assume it's a component I'm missing with my shading editor, can someone tell me what components I need or I could be missing or some sort of problem that could be wrong with my model?

Comment: Are you using PBR textures maps or procedural texturing inside Blender ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the . blend files inside the Unity project's Assets folder (or a subfolder inside Assets). You can open them for editing by double-clicking the file in Unity. ...

Place all the texture files in a subfolder named Textures in the same folder as the . blend file.